# Car won't start because of mysterious electrical problem

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, starter

I have a 2007 Honda Civic Coupe, with a 5-speed manual transmission. I've had electrical problems for about 5 months now. I had the car at an electrical shop (twice) who could find nothing wrong.

So I did my own diagnostic and found a parasitic voltage drain with the car off through the MG Clutch fuse.  I pulled the fuse and everything was fine.  I replaced the Omron relay and the problem was fixed for about 3 months.

Now, intermittently, I have to jump my car with a portable Stanley charger (best money I ever spent) to start the car.  I checked all the fuses under the hood and dash and can find no parasitic current draw.  Once in a while, the car starts normal.  But my 5 month old battery either doesn't always hold its charge, or my alternator isn't always putting out enough current to charge up my battery.  And then again, it may be my starter.  I'm going to check my battery to make sure it hasn't been ruined by 50-75 jumps.  Just yesterday, I had to charge it 3 times on my way to work, and one time after work.  It started first thing this morning, but 45 minutes later at a required stop, I had to jump it again.  I love the car but it's been such a headache, I'm ready to get rid of it.  At least you've given me a few more things to consider.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the new battery before you fixed the electrical problem it could be that it has been over discharged. Most automotive batteries don't like going dead flat and often won't hold a decent charge afterwards.

If your car starts well from a jump start then this is fairly likely to be the case.

I had exactly the same thing with my car, persistent starting trouble, eventually  traced to a faulty bonnet switch but then needed a new battery shortly afterwards. It would sometimes go dead flat and not even attempt to start.

You can get battery testers but these aren't much cheaper than a new battery.

Comment: What automotive batteries genuinely don't like is being dead flat for long amounts of time. So, if your battery went dead flat and you recharged it immediately after noticing the problem, most likely the battery will hold enough charge. I forgot lights on on my 2011 Toyota Yaris in 2013 and had to jump start, yet in 2016 the original battery still worked perfectly.